# Working of AC relay

Tags: electromagnetism

I have been wondering how an AC relay works. I know how a DC relay works. Can someone please explain about the construction and working of AC relay.

Comment: Do you mean a relay that switches AC, or a relay in which the coil is driven by AC?

Comment: Panasonic and Omron have excellent documents that explain every part of a relay, its specs and operation. Seek these out.

Answer (score 3):

The essential difference between an AC relay and a DC relay is the shading coil that maintains the magnetic flux while the current crosses through zero. See image:

[image]
[Source](https://opentextbc.ca/basicmotorcontrol/chapter/magnetic-motor-starters/)